# Not install @nivo//core in vs code problem

Tags: reactjs

I am getting the below error message:

```
npm ERR! code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL
npm ERR! Unsupported URL Type "workspace:": workspace:*
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-04T06_06_44_419Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\RUN\react-admin> npm i @nivo/core
npm ERR! code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL
npm ERR! Unsupported URL Type "workspace:": workspace:*
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-04T06_07_20_495Z-debug-0.log
```

I am using the below `npm` command to install the dependencies in my project but they are not getting installed.

```
npm i @nivo/core @nivo/pie @nivo/bar @nivo/geo
```

Comment: Check the log files for the exact errors you pointed out in your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `npm install nivo --legacy-peer-deps` it works, I also got an error but after a long search i found this

Comment: Risk of using `--legacy-peer-deps` flag, if some other library uses the peer dep's different version, it will be a mess. 
This flag is generally not recommended to use. Update your libraries instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was [an update on 26/04/23](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nivo/core?activeTab=versions) to version 0.81.0.

Using version 0.80.0 worked for me as a temporary workaround: `npm i @nivo/core@0.80.0 @nivo/pie@0.80.0 @nivo/bar@0.80.0 @nivo/geo@0.80.0`